# C# - Conectar GridControl com uma List e manipular os registros em run-time

Tags: c#, lista, devexpress

tudo bem ???

Esta é a minha primeira pergunta aqui no stack overflow, me desculpe se eu fiz algo de errado !!!

Estou começando com C# e DevExpress e estou tentando criar um exemplo usando o GridControl da DevExpress (v.19.2.5.0) com uma classe que contém alguns registros em uma Lista.

Criei um projeto simples (Windows Forms) e coloquei um GridControl e tentei conectar o GridControl à classe (Record.cs / PrototipoViewModel.cs).

O GridControl em modo designer, lista as colunas, mas em run-time, está vazio.

Onde é que eu errei ? Ou o que eu não fiz para listar os registros em run-time ?

Minha segunda pergunta seria, posso inserir, atualizar e excluir os registros em run-time diretamente no GridControl usando uma lista ?

Class Record.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Prototipo
{
    Registro de classe pública
    {
        public DateTime? Dados {get; definir; }
        public string Cliente {get; definir; }
        public string Movimento {get; definir; }
        Valor decimal público {get; definir; }

        public static List <Record> GetRecords ()
        {
            Lista <Registro> pessoas = nova Lista <Registro> ();

            people.Add (new Record () {Data = new DateTime (2021, 04, 07, 19, 00, 00), Cliente = "João", Movimento = "D", Valor = 1000});
            people.Add (new Record () {Data = new DateTime (2021, 04, 07, 19, 30, 00), Cliente = "Maria", Movimento = "D", Valor = 2000});
            people.Add (new Record () {Data = new DateTime (2021, 04, 07, 20, 00, 00), Cliente = "Jose", Movimento = "D", Valor = 3000});

            retornar pessoas;
        }
    }
}
```

Classe PrototipoViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Prototipo
{
    public class PrototipoViewModel
    {
        public PrototipoViewModel ()
        {
            this.Records = Record.GetRecords ();
        }

        Public List <Record> Records {get; definir; }
    }
}
```

e Classe frmPrototipoMain.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
usando System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Prototipo
{
    classe pública parcial frmPrototipoMain: DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public frmPrototipoMain ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
}
```

O projeto está no GitHub (https://github.com/tiago-pimenta/vs_gridcontrol_bind_class)

Obrigado

Comment: olá, não vi na sua pergunta onde faz o *bind* dos seus dados no Grid

Comment: @RicardoPontual, na aba "Fontes de Dados", criei uma do tipo "Objeto" e apontei para a classe "PrototipoViewModel" e na propriedade "Choose DataSource" da Grid, selecionei "recordsBindingSource". Foi justamente depois desse processo que apareceu as colunas em modo de design, porém não trouxe os dados.

Comment: e você chamad o `DataBind()` certo?

Comment: @RicardoPontual não, os únicos códigos realmente são esses que coloquei, e mais essa configuração que acabei fazendo no GridControl. Eu já usei o DevExpress no Delphi, lá para popular a grid, nós davamos um "Open" no DataSet/DataSource, acredito que esteja faltando um comando parecido, para dar o "Get" nos registros da classe Record.cs, só que não sei como fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Bom pessoal, consegui achar onde estava o erro no meu código, eu achei que setando a propriedade "Choose DataSource" da GridControl, bastaria, mas faltou o código abaixo:

```
private void frmPrototipoMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gridControl.DataSource = Prototipo.Record.GetRecords();
        }
```

Bom, agora me resta somente resolver o problema de permitir que o GridControl insira novas linhas, lendo a documentação da DevExpress, diz para setar as propriedades "AllowNew" e "AllowRemove" para True do DataSource, e diz também que precisa criar uma classe com uma propriedade tipo simples obrigatório e que a classe deve ter um construtor padrão vazio.

O meu DataSource, só tem a propriedade "AllowNew" e já está setado para "True", porém mesmo assim não consigo inserir novas linhas no GridControl.

A minha classe é do tipo simples obrigatório ? Ela tem o construtor padrão vazio ?

Obrigado quem ajudou até o momento !!!